# how to make encrypt in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, cryptography

i try to learn about encrypt in asp.net MVC

it's so hard to understand about it..

can some one give me simple example to use encrypt in asp.NET MVC??

i try to make simple application use encrypt in asp.net mvc. i read some article to reference about encrypt. but no one article show how to encrypt data or query with asp.net mvc 3 or 4

```
can some one give me reference about encrypt in asp.net mvc 3 / 4 or give me some simple example of encrypt..
```

Comment: What's your use case for encryption?

Comment: i use encrypt to encrypt URL to reset password, and send url to email.

Comment: What do you encrypt within that URL?

Comment: UserID to reset their password

Comment: Does that mean that I can reset anyone's password if I guess their user id and know your encryption algorithm?

Comment: oh no, i mean, if i have ID in my web, and i want to reset my password, system will send email verification to my email, if i click link in email, i will redirect to some url to reset my password.

Comment: One often-used approach is generating an unique reset password token that is only valid within a short period of time (or until used), storing it in your application, then sending the url with that token to user. But I suppose you can encrypt (id&time) instead -- not sure if there are any security considerations about that.

Comment: oh my god... can you give me simple example to use in asp.net mvc 3/4. i really really not understand how encrypt work in mvc

Answer (score 1):

here is library you can use to encrypt and decrypt your urls
http://jbtule.github.io/keyczar-dotnet/

given your use case, you are going to create the encryted url and send it in an email

for the sake of this answer, lets pretend the encypted url is

"yourdomainname/encrypted/kladsfiopfvnjladsiopdfsipejkadsjsadipodafskl"

suppose the encrypted string represents the a string which can be decrypted to the fields username, dateValidThrough, and emailaddress, seperated by "|" charachters. ie

username + "|" + datevalidthough +  "|" emailaddress

okay, so to recieve the encrypted url, you have a route in your RouteConfig.cs routes

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PaswordReset",
            url: "Encrypted/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Password", action = "Reset", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

this would take them to this contoller which has two methods

```
public class PasswordController{

  public ActionResult Reset(string id){}
    //returns a view that has a form for them to enter their username and email

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Reset(string id, string username, string email){}
   //derypt here and verify etc.

 }
```

First, they would be shown a form in which they can enter their email address and username. it should have a hidden field for the enrypted url part

When they submit the form, decrypt the id using the passphrase that you encrypted it with.

Verify that their username and email address match up. Make sure the datevalidthrough is < today, then allow them to change their password.

To make the encrypted string, you would use the library above and it would be like

```
string plaintext = userName + "|" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(2).ToString() + "|" + userEmailAddress;
WebBase64 ciphertext;
string key = (new Random().Random(10000000) + 1000).ToString();

//pretend this dictionary represents a database storage medium
public static Dictionary<string,string> CypherTextToKey= new Dictionary<string,string>();

//encrypting
using (var encrypter = new Encrypter(key))  
{
   ciphertext = encrypter.Encrypt(plaintext);
}
CypherTextToKey.Add(cyphertext, key);
SendEmail(user, "Encrypted/"+cyphertext");
```

To decrypt it you would do something like

```
var key = CypherTextToKey[cyphertext]; //get the key from your database
using (var crypter = new Crypter(key)){
  var plaintext2 = crypter.Decrypt(ciphertext)
}
```

if all matches, give them a new password, etc.

Theres a way to operate an entire site using encrypted urls, but thats a different story and I'm not sure if thats what you need (its a bit more complicated). If you want to encrypt every url make a comment and I'll get back to you with another answer.