# Encrypting form data in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

can someone help me?? im having trouble encrypting form data im currently working on the log in. i just need to secure the user name and password when im doing an ajax call could you give me some advice for that? im using MVC4 C#

Comment: Don't you want to just use SSL/TLS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make encrypt in asp.net mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100405/how-to-make-encrypt-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the data over HTTPS, which is the standard way to encrypt communications between the browser and server.