# encrypting form data in MVC through Webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

is there some codes to encrypt a form data through webconfig?
some sort of codes or in global.asax? im currently developing a log in for my website and i dont want to use SSL. is there some way to solve my problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting form data in MVC C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219620/encrypting-form-data-in-mvc-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

No. The `web.config` file only controls how the server behaves. Between the client and the server you need to rely on the HTTP protocol.

This is exactly why HTTPS (i.e. SSL) exists.  If you need to encrypt data while it is being transferred from the client browser to your web server you **must** use HTTPS.  There are no shortcuts.

Comment: Hi i just use HTTPS but when i look at in google chrome developer's tool it seems my data form is not encrypted am i missing some codes? in my solution im using IIS 7  and self singed certificate.

Comment: This is standard, the response is decrypted on the client so the client can read the response, it is the transfer of the HTTP Request / Response that is encrypted over the "wire" you will have to encrypt the data manually on the server before sending the response to the client - if you intend to display data to the users this is unnecessary - btw don't store sensitive information in cookies a common practice is to just store a session ID in a cookie, and store all other relevant information in a database (or file, or whatever) on the server, indexed by session ID.